# Flow type for function that return function

Tags: javascript, flowtype

From [flow's function type docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-function-returns), function that return `primitive type` is like this

`const a = aFunc = (id: number): number => id + 1`.

But, how to create flow type for a function that return a function?

```
const aFunc = (id: number): <what type?> => {
  return bFunc(a): void => console.log(a)
}
```

Comment: Create a delegate and you can use it the same way.

Comment: @ErickStone sorry, but I don't have a clue for it. May provide an example?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2011/07/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-5.html
This covers the basics.

Comment: e.g. `const f = (x :number) : (number => number) => y => x + y`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either create a separate type, or you can do it inline.
Or you can choose to don't specify a return-type at all, because `flow` knows the return type of `bFunc`.

```js
const bFunc = (a): void => console.log(a);
```

Separate type:

```
type aFuncReturnType = () => void;
const aFunc = (id: number): aFuncReturnType => () => bFunc(id);
```

Inline:

```
const aFunc = (id: number): (() => void) => () => bFunc(id);
```

You can also see this on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzACMAxAV2wzAF4wAKAQwEoAuMANzgEsATGgPjBY8cGAFMAdPADmjJgG50+AJ4AHMWAblKAJTH4yAJ2wAVNRtp0mAjtx6LhBTdqqXebbGQC2RMYdbOFBh6BsZm6jZWNqRBdLwK6I6EGC409O5gnj5+AXRR1IKc8ZHWBcQucTwJQA)